# why DataGridColumn.GetCellContent (DatagridRow) is always null even though DataGridRow is not null?

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls, wpfdatagrid

I am trying to access each cell content when `DataGridRow` is loaded, but the `DataGridColumn.GetCellContent(DataGridRow)` is always null though there is data in the DataGridRow for that column. 
For ex:

```
    void DataGrid_LoadingRow(object sender,DataGridRowEventArgs e)
    {
      foreach(var colItem in dg.Columns)
      {
        var cell=item.GetCellContent(e.Row as DataGridRow);//Row is not null, cell is null after this execution.       
      }
    }
```

what could be the reason?

PS: I have disabled Virtualisation of both rows and columns.

Thanks

Comment: I used updatelayout event of the datagrid,  and I was able to access the datagridcell content.

Comment: add your comment as an answer and flag it for other users to see it and to mark this question as answered

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When `DataGrid` is about loading row data in a `DataGridRow` and populating a row, it seems at first it raises the `LoadingRow` event before appling Data Bindings, etc. Therefore content of its `DataGridCell`s will be null at this point.

It is a thing similar `PropertyChanging` event (that fires before appling of change). Whereas `PropertyChanged` event fires after that change occured.

You can use another event for this purpose.

Comment: @kedarK If you think it is a true answer, Tick it as answer to help others know.

Comment: Note that this is different in Silverlight. In Silverlight you can get the grid cell content on this event.

Comment: Which event should we use?

Comment: How was this problem actually solved? Which event can we use to know that the contents of the cell have been loaded so we can get at them?

Comment: @Christian Findlay it depends on each specific situation. Because it is vary based on WPF DataGrid usage scenarios and options (specially row and column virtualization in mixture with visibility option affects on this behavior). You must test other events (considering '...ed' events rather than '...ing' ones. Or events that will occur later). I think It is simple enough. I have no time now to test for a safe appropriate event in all usage scenarios for you... excusive me.

Comment: @Christian Findlay Let me know if your problem not solved to now, and I will update my answer.

Answer (score 0):

It is a software bug so:

- change column visibility to visible
- remove `DataGridTemplateColumn`

and it will work well.